# vim - highlight for loop iterator

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

how can I highlight the iterator of a for loop?

for example, in:

```
for (int iter=0; iter<test; iter++)
   array[iter][5] = array2[iter] & (array[iter] < test2)
end
```

I want every instance of the word "iter" inside the loop to be bold and colored.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you move the cursor over iter and hit <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd> that should highlight all instances of iter, unfortunately it will highlight it for the entire script and not just the loop